# Is there an accepted name for the repeating part of a periodic sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, terminology

Let $S$ be a periodic sequence, for example 0,1,2,0,1,2, ... .

Is there an accepted name for the repeating part of $S$ - the finite sequence 0,1,2 ?

$pattern(S)$?
$mainpart(S)$?
$reppart(S)$?

Comment: $[\overline{0,1,2}]$?

Comment: See [Repetend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the "repetend".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a standard functional name like this (although you could certainly create one in something you were writing if it helped the reader). I would just call this "the periodic part of $S$" or "the finite sequence that generates $S$ periodically" in words.